# Convert 2 integers to float number

Tags: c#, integer, modbus

I need to convert 2 integers to a float number. I'm using the following function to do this conversion:

```
string hexString = value1 + value2;
uint num = uint.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

byte[] floatVals = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
f = BitConverter.ToSingle(floatVals, 0);
```

The function works fine, except when the second integer is negative. Which gives a small difference in the decimal part.

**Example:**

*16998 and 16673:* **57.76** -> Correct

*16998 and -11174:* **57.54** -> Incorrect (The correct is: **57.71**).

What I'm doing to get close to the correct number is multiplying the second integer by -1 to make it positive. My question is how to get the exact value when the second integer is negative?

**Reading the manual, it says:**

[image]

**Myy app screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: What is `value1` and `value2`? How do they relate to the 2 integers?

Comment: Value 1, 2, 3.. they're all reads. But different time intervals. "Reads" is a device read. im reading a power meter using modbus.